# Maven: include files in JAR's META-INF

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin, meta-inf

I'm using Maven to build a Java project, and I've got a couple files, `CHANGELOG` and `LICENSE`, that I'd like to copy to the `META-INF` directory inside the JAR file.

So far what I've got working is the following:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>CHANGELOG</include>
                <include>LICENSE</include>
            </includes>
            <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        ...
```

but that also copies those two files to the `classes/META-INF` directory when compiling.

So I'd like the files to be included in the JAR file, but nowhere else. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 21):

You don't need to specify any custom maven configuration to address your need.

In `src/main/resources`, simply create  a `META-INF` folder and place your files here.
In this way, you could find them in the `META-INF` folder of the built JAR.

Besides, you should remove the  `<resource>` element you added in the `pom.xml` since it changes the default resource folder to the root of the project instead of the default `src/main/resources`.

Comment: But the result is the same, right? If we just compile it will copy these resource files as well. I want them copied just to the JAR file.

Comment: not really, since in the Jar, the resources will not be duplicated in classes/META-INF. They will be only in the META-INF dir as explained.

Comment: Hi @davidxxx. I noticed your comment when the resources should go to META-INF, but is it possible to put resources in the root of the jar file, next to META-INF? Thanks.

Comment: Hi  @Cristian. Of course you can as all resources (files and folders) that you will store in your project in `src/main/resources` will be by default at the root of the built JAR.

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot and everything goes under BOOT-INF which is next to META-INF. Any idea here? Thanks.

Comment: @Cristian It is a reapckaging jar by Spring Boot to allow the application to be autobootable. It is not a classic jar. You should not bother about it. The jar will stay accessible to the application all the same. Which is your problem exactly ?

Comment: I'm deploying to AWS and I want to include in the JAR root some configuration files and a configuration folder with files. A Spring Boot jar contains the folders BOOT-INF, META-INF and org, and I want to include the folder .ebextensions and the file cron.yaml.

Comment: @Cristian You can do it with a Spring Boot autobootable WAR but not with Spring Boot autobootable JAR that is not designed to have this layout. You will indeed find your resources in `BOOT-INF\classes`. The problem is that you could not change it easily as this repackaging is performed by Spring Boot itself. You could try to create a Layout and to pass it to the `layoutFactory` property of the repackage plugin of Spring Boot but no guarantee. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#layoutFactory Anyway the question is interesting, why not ask it on SO ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add files and a directory to the META-INF folder use this code in your pom.xml

```
   <build>
        <finalName>CustomJsfComponents</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**.xml</include>
                    <include>**resources/**</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your pom by adding **webResources**

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>target/classes/META-INF/</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <targetPath>META-INF/</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Consider the config.properties file to be found in

```
src / main / resources / META-INF / config.properties
```

War example output
[image: war output example]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your files to `META-INF` when creating a `WAR`, you can create your own `META-INF` folder in `webapp` directory.

```
src/main/webapp/META-INF
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding META-INF/resources/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.ForcedAutoDiscoverable
with the following content:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.JaxbAutoDiscoverable
```

But after doing the jar package, it still contained only:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlAutoDiscoverable
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.monitoring.MonitoringAutodiscoverable
```

Then I manually edited jar so that it contains:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlAutoDiscoverable
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.monitoring.MonitoringAutodiscoverable
org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.JaxbAutoDiscoverable
```

Then application works fine.
Now I just need to find a way to add this missing line to that file.