# Copy file to jar root when building spring-boot project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, procfile

I have a Spring Boot project and I'm building the jar file with mvn clean build.
I need to copy a folder and a file to the root of the jar, where META-INF is located. I tried maven-resources-plugin but I can't reach my goal.

For war files I used maven-war-plugin in the past but I can't find something similar for jars.

Can anybody give me an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding resources location to the build section of your POM?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I don't understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: You explained that you tried using maven-resources-plugin but you didn't specify what you did exactly. You can include resources in your jar using <build><resources><resource>...</resource></resources></build> as explained in the [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html).

Comment: I tried to include the resources with <resources>...</resources> but it doesn't work if the resources should be included in the root path. I need something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833373/maven-include-files-in-jars-meta-inf but next to META-INF not inside. Still looking for an answer and testing. Thanks.

Comment: Adding my folder into the resources folder and building my project actually puts my folder at the root of my jar. Have you added your resources folder as a source folder on build path? When you extract your jar, where is located? For me, it gives me my package folder containing my classes, the META-INF folder and the one I added to resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using the maven-assembly-plugin. I created an assembly zip which contains the application jar and some other resources.
This solution is specific for applications which use AWS Elastic Beanstalk and need to implement the Procfile (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html#java-se-procfile).

Answer (score 2):

I could manage to add files after the `repackage` goal of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` using the `maven-antrun-plugin` and the Jar tool included in the JDK.

### Updating a JAR File

> The Jar tool provides a u option which you can use to update the contents of an existing JAR file by modifying its manifest or by adding files.
>
> The basic command for adding files has this format:
>
> `jar uf jar-file input-file(s)`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

### Using Maven-Antrun-Plugin

This command can be executed using the `maven-antrun-plugin` together with the `exec` task, which allows you to execute commands via `Runtime.exec(..)`.

The  entry may look like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <exec executable="jar" vmlauncher="false">
                        <arg value="uf" />
                        <arg value="${project.build.directory}/myprogram.jar" />
                        <arg value="-C" />
                        <arg value="${project.build.directory}/classes" />
                        <arg value="org/company/app/Main.class" />
                    </exec>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Notice the -C option, which allows you to change the directory that should not be included in the jar.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

### Using Exec-Maven-Plugin

Alternatively the `exec-maven-plugin` can be used which does not require [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) to be installed.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>exec</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>jar</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>uf</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/myprogram.jar</argument>
                    <argument>-C</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                    <argument>org/company/app/Main.class</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The final structure may look like this:

```
myprogram.jar
|-BOOT-INF/..
|-META-INF/..
|-org/springframework/boot/loader/..
|-org/company/app/Main.class
```

That way you can add any additional files you want after the jar has been packaged.

Answer (score 0):

could something like the following help?

See also [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/cdi/*</include>
                    <include>**/META-INF/*</include>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the include and exclude sections for maven-jar-plugin are useful only to include or exclude classes from specific packages.

Comment: Ah I see, I presume you want to copy from a place outside of your module src. I would have to check if a relative path can be used something like ../../<othermodule>/resources/global.properties
The documentation states: "Note that the patterns need to be relative to the path specified for the plugin's classesDirectory parameter."

Comment: Indeed, I have a folder resources next to src and target, and I want to include it's contents in the root of the generated jar file, next to META-INF and BOOT-INF.

Comment: why not parallel to src/main/java?  That could be included this way, since that would be copied to the target directory. if you don't want the resources in other goals, you can exclude these there at will.

Comment: If I put those config files in src/main/resources, next to other resources, everything gets copied into /target/classes. From there they go to the jar file in BOOT-INF/classes.

Comment: I suspect there is an additional plugin working. normally the jar-plugin should put everything from classes into the root of the jar-file. Sorry, you might need a spring-boot expert. Perhaps change your tags.